# Getting a Nan Error SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, nan

Getting a NaN error. My original statement is:

```
=SUM(Fields!Outstanding_Commitments.Value/Fields!Conversion.Value, "Cost")
```

After getting the NaN error, i changed my code to the following:

```
=IIF(Double.IsNAN(SUM(Fields!Outstanding_Commitments.Value/Fields!Conversion.Value, "Cost"))
,0,
SUM(Fields!Outstanding_Commitments.Value/Fields!Conversion.Value, "Cost"))
```

Using the second part doesnt provide me with any values at all. Something isn't right.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the expression below

```
=SUM(
Iif(Fields!Conversion.Value=0,0,Fields!Outstanding_Commitments.Value)
/
Iif(Fields!Conversion.Value=0,1,Fields!Conversion.Value)
, "Cost")
```